# Allow users to enter and edit data in one-to-many configuration

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, database, forms

We would want a user to login and be presented with a form that they would potentially have to submit multiple times (disclosures of any industry relationships, one form per disclosure).

The challenge is how do we capture and display what has been previously entered by a user when they log back in and give them a chance to delete or edit previous entries without investing in a ton of custom coding because we have a very tight deadline on this project.

Has anyone seen WordPress do data collection and management in this manner on a per-user basis and if so, which plugins or other add ins were used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Formidable Pro plugin](http://formidablepro) (paid) does what I was describing.  It allows a logged-in user to submit a form multiple times and also will display a list of entries and a link to edit each one.  Gravity and Wufoo don't match up.

Answer (score 0):

You can just alter the default user profile fields and add/remove whatever you want or use a plugin that does so. Alternatively you can use plugin like gravity forms or wufoo.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm after. The user logs in and has to make 1 to infinity entries via a form and then be able to come back later and edit or delete those entries.  Gravity Forms is great at intake, but less good with querying data back out unless I'm missing something in the documentation.